# Issue with storing data within an Array - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, database, swift3, swift4

I currently have my set-up as followed:

I am running a query in Firebase to extract all of the genres within an array of genres, like so:

```
var genresLabelIndex : [String] = ["Horror", "Fiction", "Romance"]
```

Then I am creating a blank arrays for each of the genres to be able to store the information of the genres within each of the areas like so:

```
var horrorData = [InformationForFeed]()
var fictionData = [InformationForFeed]()
var romanceData = [InformationForFeed]()
```

InformationForFeed looks like so:

```
class InformationForFeed {


    fileprivate var _uploadKey:String!
    fileprivate var _userKey:String!
    fileprivate var _imageURL:String!
    fileprivate var _socialMedia:[String]



    var uploadKey:String!{
        return _uploadKey
    }
    var userKey:String!{
        return _userKey
    }
    var imageURL:String!{
        return _imageURL
    }


    init(dictionary:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>, socials: [String]) {

        _socialMedia = socials

        if let uploadKey = dictionary["upload_key"] as? String {
            self._uploadKey = uploadKey
        }
        if let userKey = dictionary["user_key"] as? String {
            self._userKey = userKey
        }
        if let imageURL = dictionary["imageUrl"] as? String {
            self._imageURL = imageURL
        }
    }
}
```

I am then creating an Array of the list of genres arrays like so:

1) First I am creating an empty array of arrays like this:

```
var genreArrayIndex : [[InformationForFeed]] = []
```

2) Then within my init() of the UIView I am setting what will be in the array like this:

```
genreArrayIndex = [self.horrorData, self.fictionData, self.romanceData]
```

I then will run a function called `getData()` that will run my query and start storing the information.

I store my information of each genre in a `tempArray`, and then I set the `genreArrayIndex[index]` to equal the `tempArray` and then clear the `tempArray` as seen in `getData` below.

```
func getData() {

    for genre in genresLabelIndex {
        let dbReference = Database.database().reference().child("genres").child(genre)
        let query = dbReference.queryLimited(toLast: 6)


        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot : DataSnapshot) in

            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

                for s in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

                    let item = s.value as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject?>
                    let facebook = (s.childSnapshot(forPath: "social_links").value as? NSDictionary)?["facebook_link"]
                    let audible = (s.childSnapshot(forPath: "social_links").value as? NSDictionary)?["audible_link"]
                    let amazon = (s.childSnapshot(forPath: "social_links").value as? NSDictionary)?["amazon_link"]

                    var socialsArray = [String]()

                    if facebook != nil {
                        socialsArray.append(facebook! as! String)
                    } else {
                        socialsArray.append("nil")
                    }

                    if audible != nil {
                        socialsArray.append(audible! as! String)
                    } else {
                        socialsArray.append("nil")
                    }

                    if amazon != nil {
                        socialsArray.append(amazon! as! String)
                    } else {
                        socialsArray.append("nil")
                    }

                    let data = InformationForFeed(dictionary: item as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>, socials: socialsArray)

                        self.newArray.append(data)
                }


            }


            self.genreArrayIndex[self.genreArrayIndexCount] = self.newArray
            self.genreArrayIndexCount = self.genreArrayIndexCount + 1
            self.newArray.removeAll()

            self.internalIndex = self.internalIndex + 1
            if self.internalIndex == self.genresLabelIndex.count {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }


        })

    }

}
```

My `tempArray` looks like this:
`var newArray = [InformationForFeed]()`

The `index` looks like this:

`var genreArrayIndexCount : Int = 0`

Now comes the issue....

All of the information is properly being stored in the `genreArrayIndex` .....but... it is not actually storing the information in the arrays that being stored in `genreArrayIndex`.

So in other words if you were to `print(self.genreArrayIndex)` it would be fully populated. But if you were to `print(self.fictionData)` it would be blank.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array is a value type. That means its contents are copies. Initializing `genreArrayIndex` with empty `horrorData`, (and others) and then filling it with `getData()` does not also copy the data back into `horrorData`. I would recommend eliminating

```
genreArrayIndex = [self.horrorData, self.fictionData, self.romanceData]
```

and replacing `horrorData`, `fictionData`, ... with computed properties. Perhaps like this.

```
var horrorData: [InformationFeed] {
   return genreArrayIndex[0]
}
```

Comment: This result in an error that `Instance genreArrayIndex cannot be used on type UIView (Name of the UIView)`

Comment: I have resolved this, by doing `get {
            return genreArrayIndex[0]
        }`

Within each of the array variables & setting genreArrayIndex to be = [[],[],[]]